# Cannot run instrumentation tests after I introduced databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm getting

`Warning: library class android.databinding.DataBindingUtil depends on program class android.databinding.DataBindingComponent`

I get this when attempting to run the gradle task `assembleItestAndroidTest` after introducing data binding to my project. (I have a separate build config for instrumentation testing which I call `itest`, the other two being debug and release)

How to fix this?

**edit**: I think this is a android-gradle build tool bug or Android Data Binding bug. I've filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196238) to Google with full instructions on how to reproduce.

The key here is that the build type is configured to run minification. So any build type other than `debug` for the instrumentation test will fail as long as you rely on data binding.

This is pretty much a show-stopper for any company having continous integration as an integral part of their production cycle so I hope Google prioritize this high.

Comment: they had a problem with the first apha release of the build tools, try              classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2

Comment: Upgraded to AS 2.0 preview 2 and to that gradle build tools version but it did not help :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your proguard config:

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class <whatever your package name in AndroidManifest is>.databinding.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

The first line gets rid of the warning, and the second tells proguard to not mess with any of the generated classes.